# JDK 8u74 64-bit + 32-bit + NetBeans.

Tags: java-8, 64-bit, 32-bit, netbeans-8

I want to install BOTH the 64-bit and 32-bit JDK 8u7**4** on Windows 7 Pro 64-bit AND NetBeans.  I want NetBeans to use the correct JVM depending on whether I code in 32 or 64-bit. I found zero info about the right way to go about this.  Do I install the 32-bit JDK 8u74, then 64-bit JDK 8u74, then NetBeans?
I have no JDK installed now.  I am just getting started and would really love to avoid an install nightmare and operating problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "I code in 32 or 64 bit"? Are you writing native code?

Comment: What do you mean by "depending on whether I code in 32 or 64-bit"? The Java language doesn't really distinguish; that's a property of the JVM on which your program runs. If you're writing native code, then perhaps your question should be with respect to the NDK, not the JDK.

Comment: If all you want is to write plain java code, then you can install whichever you like - the 64bit version will be able to access more RAM than the 32 bit version but will also use a more memory. If you don't know/care, just go for the 64 bit version.